# Does Prism provide a mechanism for commands that close a window?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

I believe that I saw somewhere that [Prism](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism) provides a WPF mechanism for implementing `ICommand` that closes a window. I've been looking over the documentation but it's overwhelming and I can't seem to pinpoint anything about this (if it even exists). Does Prism have MVVM helpers for closing, or even creating, windows via view model command binding?

I do see that you can do it a more "manual" way, without Prism, but Prism does provide helpers for other similar tasks.

Comment: I'm almost 100% prism does not provide an ICommand implementation aimed at windows/views closing. The question is why do you need prism to assist you with this. Normally I want to be in control for dirty checking, disposing etc.

Comment: I was aiming to go with an approach that put commands in the view model. Some commands make sense in the view model and fit in there easily, such as reloading data, etc. Other command-likes don't seem to fit in there easily. I've just gone with an approach that uses code-behind for things that need to close the window.

Comment: But you can still use your own implementation for windows closing from viewmodel using commands, not need to fall back to code behind.

Comment: Yup. MVVM is about decoupling view and logic. It should be able to run headless. If you put your commands in the view, I don't think that would be easy. 
I use a service interface to abstract away the implementation details which calls window.close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Prism doesn't provide any helpers for closing a Window.  This can be done with standard MVVM techniques, and there is nothing special needed to accomplish this..